# How to install apache-spark 2.3.3 with homebrew on Mac

Tags: apache-spark, homebrew

`$brew install apache-spark` only installs the most recent version of spark (2.4) and `$brew search apache-spark` does not give any other options. Is there a way to install an older version of spark with homebrew?

Answer (score 6):

Type

```
brew tap eddies/spark-tap
```

Then install the specific version

```
brew install apache-spark@2.3.3
```

Comment: Hi i want to install 3.1.1 but when I run `brew install apache-spark@3.1.1`, but it says `No available formula with the name "apache-spark@3.1.1"`

Answer (score 1):

```
brew tap eddies/spark-tap
brew install apache-spark@2.3.2
```