# Error: No available formula or cask with the name "apache-spark@2.4.3"

Tags: macos, apache-spark, homebrew

I am trying to install apache-spark version 2.4.3. when I ran

```
brew install apache-spark@2.4.3
```

this is what I am getting

```
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "apache-spark@2.4.3".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

can someone help?

Comment: You could refer to this code,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56601226/how-to-install-apache-spark-2-3-3-with-homebrew-on-mac This helped me.